# Is there anything special about the blue mutants?

Tags: the-forest

[image]

I wonder why do some of the mutants have blue skin rather than pink. Is it just for variety or does it mean something?

Comment: Is the whole game really dark like the screenshot? I can barely see anything...

Comment: At night when you have no lighter, torch, or flashlight, yes. Survival-horror crafting game. Of course the game has plenty of light sources and it's day half the time. Speaking of the darkness in the screenshot though, is it possible the mutants only look blue because of lighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this wiki https://theforest.gamepedia.com/Mutant

> Blue Armsys are identical to regular Armsy’s with the exception of
>   greater damage and health. It is possible they may be faster.

Basically the blue mutants are harder to kill.